# How to grant nobody openvpn access to the ccd directory?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, privileges

I need to distribute static addresses to some openvpn clients, which I decided to do via `ccd`.
I would also like to downgrade the privileges of the openvpn daemon for more security.
Unfortunately, these two desires do not want to be combined.

openvpn claims that it cannot access the profile file in any way:

```
test1/X.X.X.X:32767 Could not access file '/etc/openvpn/ccd/test1': Permission denied (errno=13)
test1/X.X.X.X:32767 Could not access file '/etc/openvpn/ccd/DEFAULT': Permission denied (errno=13)
```

In the openvpn settings, of course, I put:

```
# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
user nobody
group nogroup
```

`ls -l` of `openvpn`:

```
# ls -l /etc/openvpn
total 16
drw-rw-rw- 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Oct 16 23:51 ccd
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root    4096 Oct 16 21:27 client
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root    4096 Oct 16 21:54 server
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    1468 Oct 16 21:27 update-resolv-conf
```

`ls -l` of `ccd`:

```
# ls -l /etc/openvpn/ccd/
total 8
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup 42 Oct 16 23:51 test1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup 42 Oct 16 23:51 test2
```

I tried to disable `apparmor` - it didn't help. Distributive: `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`

Tried to use `/tmp` folder - same problem.

**Is it possible to force openvpn to work with ccd with reduced privileges(nobody:nogroup)? How?**